# RequireJS and TypeScript Class - Cannot call function externally

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript

I am having a tough figuring out how to mix RequireJs and TypeScript.  I am compiling TypeScript with the AMD option.  The problem is, the function declared within an exported class is classified as "prototype".  Is this normal?

**ModalHelper.ts:**

```
export class ModalHelper {
    saySomething = (something: String) => {
        alert(something);
    }
}
```

**Compiled ModalHelper.js:**

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    var ModalHelper = (function () {
        function ModalHelper() {
            this.saySomething = function (something) {
                alert(something);
            };
        }
        return ModalHelper;
    })();
    exports.ModalHelper = ModalHelper;
});
```

Create.ts and Create.js (module is marked as required):

```
require(["jquery", "Shared/ModalHelper"], function ($, modal) {
    $(function () {
        modal.ModalHelper.saySomething("hi");
    });
});
```

Why am I not able to call this function?  From debugging, I see the module being added via RequireJs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO classes in TypeScript should be used only if you need multiple instances with data associated to each instance. A Helper is usually just a bunch of static methods. Therefore I suggest to use a module instead (untested):

**Shared/ModalHelper.ts**

```
module ModalHelper {
    export function saySomething(something: String) {
        alert(something);
    }
}

export = ModalHelper
```

**Create.ts**

```
import ModalHelper = require("./Shared/ModalHelper");

module Create {
    ModalHelper.saySomething("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two options.

You are calling it like a static method, so you could make it static:

```
export class ModalHelper {
    static saySomething = (something: String) => {
        alert(something);
    }
}
```

Or if you didn't mean for it to be static, you can instantiate the `ModalHelper` first instead:

```
var helper = new ModalHelper();
helper.saySomething("hi");
```